# Pig: Regular Expression syntax

Tags: java, regex, apache-pig

I am using string comparison using regular expression in pig script.

I know that regular expression in PIG are same as Java.

The problem I am facing is: I need to remove all the character which contain white space at the trailing end ?

My regular expression is this: `(name matches '!\\s+$')`

Sample Script-----

```
raw_data = load '$input' using PigStorage(',') as (fname:chararray);
filter_data = filter raw_data by (fname matches '!\\s+$');
dump filter_data;
```

Sample Input-----

```
abcd    ,123
pqrs,234
xyz ,234
lmn,2345
```

It is not writing anything on `STDOUT`, where as it should have written `"pqrs"` and `"lmn"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `PIG`, but in Java one syntactically-correct regex to match `pqrs,234` and `lmn,2345` and would be:

```
^\S+$
```

assuming you were in `multiline`  mode.

- In Java you escape backslashes, so that turns into `^\\S+$`
- In Java you can turn on `multiline` with `(?m)` so a regex could be `(?m)^\\S+$`

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aN0cF3).